# Wordpress no muestra información de plugin o temas

Tags: wordpress

ante todo gracias a esta comunidad y a sus creadores, recién he instalado wordpress para crear la web de mi empresa todo funciona perfectamente excepto por la información que debe mostrar el sistema cuando intento buscar un plugin o un tema desde el panel de administración. Es válido aclarar que el yo(Mi empresa) soy mi propio hosting, o sea yo manejo los servidores. Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia de si me falta algo por incorporarle a la instalación de php???o alguna idea del problema??[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Mi firewal es pfsense y ahora mismo tengo una regla que permite a la ip de la web todo el trafico de entrada y salida(solo para probar), a demas puedo ver y configurar wp-googlemaps y todo se muestra correctamente

Comment: Deberías activar el debug para ver el error. wp-config.php => define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En general poner imagenes de tu error es mala idea, y para colmo WP dice algo anduvo mal y nada mas y es peor. Podrias revisar y activar el log de wp para ver si aparece algo (con suerte). Tambien en la imagen se ve que no tenes conexion de red o esta mal... puede que tengas un firewall bloqueando algo. Podrian ser mil cosas :(

Comment: Con la información que das, puede ser desde la mala configuración del servidor, hasta tu firewall que bloquee a wordpress.

Prueba a desactivar el firewall antes de meterte con el servidor. Si no funciona, activa el debug en wp-config.php para obtener más información del error.

Comment: instalate el [wp cli](https://wp-cli.org/) y fijate que te dice al ejecutar [`wp plugin list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/list/) en la carpeta de instalación de wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Vuelve a subir unicamente la carpeta de plugins con el ftp en la siguiente ruta:

tudominio/wp-content/

si no tienes ftp puedes subirlo desde el cpanel